# Adding current folder as a prefix to file name without duplication

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, batch-rename

I'm trying to piece together a batch file that will add the current folder name as a prefix to all files within that folder. In addition this needs to be able to run multiple times without duplicating the prefix.

I found this one that is almost what I need! The only problem is that it duplicates the prefix every time it's run. If someone could point me in the right direction I would be very great full!!

```
@echo off
pushd "Folder"
for /d %%D in (*) do (
  pushd "%%D"
  for /r %%F in (*) do (
    for %%P in ("%%F\..") do (
      ren "%%F" "%%~nxP_%%~nxF"
    )
  )
  popd
)
popd
```

This was an answer posted by https://superuser.com/users/109090/dbenham to the question [Add folder name to beginning of filename](https://superuser.com/questions/516082/add-folder-name-to-beginning-of-filename)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next code snippet shows a possible approach (one of many ways); note that operational `ren` command is merely echoed (`echo ren ...`) for debugging purposes:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
goto :skipProcedures

:testPrefix
call set "newN=%%oldN:*%prfx%=%%"
if /i not "%oldN%"=="%newN%" if /i "%oldN%"=="%prfx%%newN%" set "ToRename="
goto :eof

:skipProcedures
pushd "Folder"
for /d %%D in (*) do (
  pushd "%%D"
  for /r %%F in (*) do (
    for %%P in ("%%F\..") do (
      set "ToRename=Yes"
      set "prfx=%%~nxP_"
      set "oldN=%%~nxF"
      call :testPrefix
      if defined ToRename (
        echo ren "%%F" "%%~nxP_%%~nxF"
      ) else (
        echo prefixed already "%%F" "%%~nxF"
      )
    )
  )
  popd
)
popd
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G`, `%~1` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`%variable:StrToFind=NewStr%` etc.) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: works great after I deleted the 'echo'. I assume thats what you meant by it being for debugging.