# Prefix filenames with several parent folder names in cmd

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

### Challenge

Expanding on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/516082/add-folder-name-to-beginning-of-filename) post, how can you prefix filenames to include their parent folder names. @dbenham response (see below) is great, but it only prefix' the immediate parent folder's name in filename. No Powershell allowed!

#### Before:

> **C:\Photos\cats**
>   fileA.txt
>   fileB.txt
>   fileC.txt

#### After:

> **C:\Photos\cats**
>   Photos_cats_fileA.txt
>   Photos_cats_fileB.txt
>   Photos_cats_fileC.txt

*Where the divider "_" can be any character.*

### Near Solution

@dbenham's code from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/516082/add-folder-name-to-beginning-of-filename) post is as follows:

```
@echo off
pushd "Folder"
for /d %%D in (*) do (
  pushd "%%D"
  for /r %%F in (*) do (
    for %%P in ("%%F\..") do (
      ren "%%F" "%%~nxP_%%~nxF"
    )
  )
  popd
)
popd
```

#### What it does

> **C:\Photos\cats**
>   cats_fileA.txt
>   cats_fileB.txt
>   cats_fileC.txt

Again, this doesn't include "Photos". How to include?

*Pre-emptive thank you!*

Answer (score 0):

In order to include the full filepath, you will need to do some variable processing, which doesn't work in batch `for` loops without enabling delayed expansion.

Use the batch file below in place of what you had originally.

```
@echo off
pushd "Folder"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /d %%D in (*) do (
  pushd "%%D"
  for /r %%F in (*) do (
    for %%P in ("%%F\..") do (
      set _path=%%~pnxP
      set _path=!_path:~1!
      ren "%%F" "!_path:\=_!_%%~nxF"
    )
  )
  popd
)
popd
```

The differences are:

- `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` - enable delayed expansion
- `set _path=%%~pnxP` - create a variable to store the full path (excluding the drive letter) of the file
- `set _path=!_path:~1!` - the full path includes the `\` in `C:\` at the beginning, so we need to strip that out.
- `echo "%%F" "!_path:\=_!_%%~nxF"` - replace the backslashes with underscores